Why Textattack doesn't working with CUML models?
I am new to the platform and also for using GPU. Earlier, I have used the Textattack library for one of my projects using sklean and keras models. For that, I created the customModelWrappers according to the preprocessing and the models, and they worked fine.
Now since my data is different and very big, I want to implement it using GPU for the same (sklearn) models.
I have the understanding that sklearn models do not implement on GPU and I have to use CUML instead. But when I use it and pass the cuml models to customModelWrapper which I created earlier, it gives me the following error.
len() of unsized object
And stops the execution.
Additional Information:  For the vectorization of my data, I am using CountVectorizer of cuml, which is the reason of this error. Instead when I use countVectorizer of sklearn, it does the attack but doesn't use GPU resources (of course). Please help me in this.
I am attaching my modelWrapper here:
class CustomModelWrapper(textattack.models.wrappers.ModelWrapper):
    def __init__(self, model, vectorizer):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.vectorizer = vectorizer
    
    def __call__(self, text_input_list, batch=None):
        x_transform = self.vectorizer.transform(pd.Series(text_input_list))
        prediction = self.model.predict_proba(x_transform)
        return prediction

I expected the cuml to behave like sklearn and perform the attack using GPU resources, instead it gives me the error mentioned.
